# Why is Selenium not scraping all the data as it scrolls?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm sure the answer is simple, but it's really throwing me through a loop. I'm trying to scrape Twitter.com reply section as it infinitely scrolls. Using Selenium and bs4, I'm able to scrape only a handful of usernames. The number depends on the run, but usually varies around 7-10 usernames. It seems like it's only scraping the username at the very bottom of the page, and I'd like to scrape them all and am finding it difficult. Any help is deeply appreciated!

```
import requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html


url = ("https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1265827032707072000")
driver = webdriver.Chrome('INSERTDRIVERHERE')

def scroll_to_bottom(driver):

    old_position = 0
    new_position = None

    while new_position != old_position:
        # Get old scroll position
        old_position = driver.execute_script(
                ("return (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ?"
                 " window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement ||"
                 " document.body.parentNode || document.body);"))
        # Sleep and Scroll
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.execute_script((
                "var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement ||"
                " document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop ="
                " scrollingElement.scrollHeight;"))
        # Get new position
        new_position = driver.execute_script(
                ("return (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ?"
                 " window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement ||"
                 " document.body.parentNode || document.body);"))



driver.get(url)
scroll_to_bottom(driver)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='lxml')
usernameSoup = soup.find_all("div", class_="css-901oao css-bfa6kz r-111h2gw r-18u37iz r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-16dba41 r-ad9z0x r-bcqeeo r-qvutc0")

# Quits browser
driver.quit()

# Grabs text of css code
list_of_usernames = [x.text for x in usernameSoup]

# Lists all the usernames in a string
text = ', '.join(list_of_usernames)

# Prints list to see how many usernames are being scraped for comparison 
print(text)
print(len(list_of_usernames))
```

I've tried inserting more sleep statements to ensure that the entire page is loading before the html is parsed, but I'm still not having any luck.

Comment: some of these sites will add new content when it scrolls and remove content which has moved up and offscreen... so what you have is more like a stream of data.  Inspect the page after scroll/dom update to confirm.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to scrape a stream of data?

Comment: sure.  Just gather, scroll, gather scroll... add data you need to an array and check "contains" before adding...